# "Allow from" remote hostname works but not when using SetEnvIf in .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

In .htaccess, I am trying to restrict access by remote hostname, e.g. requests coming from googlebot.com. I have found the following works:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from googlebot.com
```

However, this doesn't work when using `SetEnvIf` as follows

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Host googlebot.com friendly_robot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=friendly_robot
```

Can anybody explain to me why the first instance works but the second one doesn't? I have spent hours reading online and cannot understand why it doesn't work with `SetEnvIf`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the dot in your SetEnvIf regular expression? Something like

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Remote_Host googlebot\.com$ friendly_robot
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, as well as all kinds of regex variations. It doesn't work.